# Is "Date" a keyword in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a column, named 'Date' using an update query as follows.
UPDATE db1 SET Date = '20130304' WHERE Date = '3/4/2013';

But the update is not taking place. Is "Date" a keyword in MySQL? If yes, then how to include it in a query so that it gets treated as a variable instead of as a keyword of MySQL.

Comment: 1. Run this: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db1 WHERE [Date] = '3/4/2013' -- this will tell you if any data matches your where clause. Comment with the result. It could be due to the datatype of the column Date. Bad name for a column too.

Comment: Hi, this date value is already there,

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B779-pgf8mqDV2JPN1RybnlMRE0/edit?usp=sharing

the query given above was part of a python script, you can check it, if more information needed

Comment: Try wrapping the column name in [], such as my example: [Date]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Date** is a keyword in mysql

```
UPDATE db1 SET Date = '20130304' WHERE Date = '3/4/2013';
```

should be

```
UPDATE db1 SET `Date` = '20130304' WHERE `Date` = '3/4/2013';
```

Comment: This is wrong. [`MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following list: ACTION, BIT, DATE, ENUM, NO, TEXT, TIME, TIMESTAMP
`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

Answer (score -2):

use `backtick` to escape keyword instead. just like how you created your table. using double quote or single quote will parse it into `string` that is why you're getting records of `Date`

Or

use decent column names

Answer (score -2):

date is the reserved word in database, try to cover it with bracket

```
UPDATE db1 SET [Date] = '20130304' WHERE [Date] = '3/4/2013';
```