# Php MySQLI statement skips the 'if' statement to 'else' without any possible mistake in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I m trying to get the existing values from "useravailedlockedcoupons" table and  update it to the  "usercouponunlock" table.

But unfortunately the update 'if' statement gets skips to 'else' without showing any error. (shows only 'none' which i have kept for 'else' statement) then executes the redirected php.page

The code follows:

```
<?php include('userdeleteunlocked.php'); ?>
<?php
$servername  = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "";

$mobile = $_SESSION['mobile'];
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM useravailedlockedcoupons WHERE mobile = '$mobile' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
        $amount = $row['amount'];
        $company = $row['company'];
        $sql2 = "UPDATE usercouponunlock SET amount = '$amount', company = '$company', date = '$date2'
                WHERE mobile = '$mobile'";

        if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
            echo  '<a href="userdeleteunlocked"></a>';
        } else {
            echo "0";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "None";
} 
$conn->close();
?>
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: You need to indent your code blocks. You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: can you elaborate please. i quite didn't get you..

Comment: It's for code readability, not an answer. Your conditionals are hard to see where they start/end because they aren't indented. You should use a tab or spaces for the start, and contents of, of each control block `{}`. Is the `session` started?

Comment: I think your mysql_num_rows = 0

Comment: @mirko911 OP is using mysqli_ not mysql_ - as a sidenote

Comment: @mirko911 No in my database, i have a table and rows mentioned for each in the code above...

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: `var_dump($_GET["id"]);` what is the value of that GET array also and the db schema for all this? and `var_dump($_SESSION['mobile']);`

Comment: The first if is getting skipped? Try echoing out your query to see if it looks the way you think it should, and try running it directly in mysql.

Comment: and which `if` statement are we talking about here?

Comment: @Anant why tick `date`? it's not a reserved word. Edit: you deleted your comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i got confused with Date:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/17873501/4248328

Comment: @Anant it's wrong and they received a few downvotes because of it, and the comment under the answer received upvotes. and all other answers given in there are wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  agreed. sorry for looking in a hurry

Comment: @Anant If in the rare case where a table/column uses `date` and is treated as a function, then I would agree that it would need to be ticked. No need to be sorry ;-)

Comment: @Anant If you read that question again http://stackoverflow.com/q/17873401/1415724 you'll see that nobody really "answered" the "real" question. Read it over again and it was also tagged as `mysql` and not another RDBMS.

Comment: Guys code been edited.. i did some changes i can do (favorable to me) please take a luk. Thanks.

Comment: someone posted an answer below; see that. I've done what I could in comments but didn't any response from them.

Answer (score 2):

Your SELECT and the associated PHP code is completely redundant. All you need is an improved update statement.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE userpaytoget SET usercouponinhand = usercouponinhand+?, date = ?, date2 = ? WHERE mobile = ?";
```

As you can see from the above, it's quite possible to update a table without selecting the rows first and iterating through it.

Notice how prepared statements are used here to protect against SQL injection.

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$_GET["id"] , $date, $date2, $mobile);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Might want `isss`.

Comment: Thanks @chris85 for the suggesition. Yes, we shouldn't rely too much on coercion to int.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference though